# Spinner being difficult to click. Upon clicking it throws a warning about already being disposed

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner that works perfect normally, but at times it doesn't show the drop down menu upon taping on it. The logcat shows following warning when the drop down menu is not shown upon tap

> W/InputEventReceiver(2909): Attempted to finish an input event but the
>   input event receiver has already been disposed.

Here is my code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.house_number_status_view, container, false);
    initializeUIResources();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setListeners();
}

private void setListeners() {
    spnHouseStatus.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

/**
 * initializes the UI resources
 */
private void initializeUIResources() {

    spnHouseStatus = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spn_houseStatus_newAcitivity);
    SpinAdapter<HouseBO> houseStatusAdapter = new SpinAdapter<HouseBO>(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
    spnHouseStatus.setAdapter(houseStatusAdapter);
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long arg3) {
    if (position != 0 && view != null) {
        switch (adapterView.getId()) {
        case R.id.spn_houseStatus_newAcitivity:
            HouseBO houseObject = (HouseBO) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am getting the same issue currently.

Comment: Sorry bro, could not find any solution so far. What exactly are you facing? if its just a warning then you can ignore it as i can roughly recall some answer which said that warning is not  harmful.